# How can $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ be expressed as a function of $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau}$ given relativistic coordinates?

Tags: partial-derivative, special-relativity

If $\phi(x,y,z,t)$ is a scalar field, given the relation between Minkowski Space coordinates $c^2(d \tau)^2 = c^2(d t)^2 - (d x)^2 -(d y)^2 -(d z)^2$, how can $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ be expressed as a function of $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau}$ and other partial derivatives (such as $\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$, etc)?

If this were an ordinary derivative, I could apply the chain rule and write

$\frac{d \phi}{d t} = \frac{d \phi}{d \tau}\frac{d \tau}{d t}$

but the chain rule for partial derivatives is tricky (for me) to use in this particular case because the variables here are not independent, and I am not changing between sets of coordinates either.

Comment: To know what $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau}$ should mean, we have to know what other variables are in play in the coordinate system where we intend to measure change with respect to $\tau$. A partial derivative is always answering the question "how does $a$ change as we hold $b, c, d$, etc.  constant." Both parts are necessary. What is changing? What is constant?

Comment: So even though you don't think you're changing between sets of coordinates, you are.

Answer (score 1):

By definition
$$
\Delta \tau(c) = \int_{c} \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{c^2} \left(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 + \dot{z}^2 \right)} \, \, dt
$$
where $\dot{x}$ is shorthand for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $c$ is a path through space-time. Can you take it from here?

I don't know a rigorous way to get the correct partial derivatives directly from the metric. For a physicist, the "chain rule" is a good enough explanation (it's the one I got in my GR class).

Comment: hmm... if I'm not mistaken, I could write $\frac{d \phi}{d \tau} = \frac{d \phi}{d t} (\frac{d \tau}{dt})^{-1} + \frac{d \phi}{d x} (\frac{d \tau}{dx})^{-1} + \frac{d \phi}{d y} (\frac{d \tau}{dy})^{-1} + \frac{d \phi}{d z} (\frac{d \tau}{dz})^{-1}$ but isn't that the ordinary derivative again? Or should I have written $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} (\frac{d \tau}{dt})^{-1} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} (\frac{d \tau}{dx})^{-1} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} (\frac{d \tau}{dy})^{-1} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} (\frac{d \tau}{dz})^{-1}$?

Comment: It comes down to deciding what else $\phi$ is a function of when you change $t$ to $\tau$. Are you looking at the coordinate transformation $(t, x, y, z) \mapsto (\tau, x, y, z)$?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. I really was mistaken when I thought I wasn't changing coordinates.

Comment: Then I think the latter formula is correct, except everything should be partial derivatives. And I believe that the $\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}$ etc. should be $0$.

Comment: But if they are all partial derivatives, then $\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau} \neq (\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t})^{-1}$ and I'll have to calculate that derivative by solving the equation you wrote for $t$.

Comment: Hmm yes. I think the difficulty here is that $\tau$ is path dependent, so it's just not clear to me what a partial derivative should mean.

Comment: In my opinion, one should only think of $d\tau$ as a $1$-form defined by $\gamma d\tau = dt$. If we want to talk about $\frac{d \phi}{dt}$ and $\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}$, we should have a worldline in mind along which we're measuring $\tau$ and $t$. That is, we should consider $\phi(c(t))$ where $c$ is a worldline.